# How to inspect any data change in one composed popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, d3.js, reactjs

I have one notification on the web, when I click on it, it will open new popup, the save button is default disable, this popup is one kind of window that composed from many elements (list of radio check boxes of many id of goods have just imported to my shop, from that I can choose one or multiple id to attach them to one shelf, and I can do the second time to attach other/others to another shelf, the name of shelf will display under the name of kind of ids...and many others elements).

Question is, how can I inspect that there is any data change (there is any id already attached or cancel attach) in order to enable the button again by Javascript.

[image: Picture].

Thank you!

Comment: This question is too broad to answer. Still you may want to try `socket.io`

Comment: @sagar patro: I cannot find a solution right now, I need any implementable solution, I do not know socket.io, maybe I will try to research. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if what you want is to "enable" the button just add the code to the `onClick` event of the "list radio check" controls, something like:

```
<form action="">
  <input type="radio" onclick="activate()" name="good1" value="1">12345746<br/>
  <input type="radio" onclick="activate()" name="good2" value="2">456548765<br/>
  <input type="radio" onclick="activate()" name="good3" value="3">54654654546<br/>
  <button id="saveButton" disable> save</button>
</form>

<script>
     function activate(){      
            document.getElementById("saveButton").disabled = false;
            //the code that enable your button, what ever serve you better...
</script>
```

or add an event listener to the click event on all the radio buttons, which will do the same (because is "the same")

```
let rb = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(let idx=0; idx<rb.length; idx++){
    if(rb[idx].getAttribute("type") == "radio"){
       rb[idx].addEventListener("click", function(){
              document.getElementById("saveButton").disabled = false;
            }
    }
}
```

which again, do the same ;)

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I actually must use angularjs model to inspect the change of click box. I must close topic because it is too broad and is not suitable as a question. Sorry for answer late.